# How to get associated groups of a SPFolder?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I am involved in a task to get list of folders and its permissioned groups from a site collection. I am getting the folder list using SPWeb.Folders. I don't have any clue to get the groups that has permission to each SPFolder.

```
foreach(SPFolder folder in SPWeb.Folders)
{
   Console.WriteLine(folder.Name);

   // Here I need to get the associated groups of folder.
}
```

Thanks in Advance for your replies.

Answer (score 0):

Does this help?

```
SPContext.Current.Web.GetFolder("/foldername").Item.CheckPermissions(...);
```